# Need help changing default js toggle state on page load

Tags: javascript, youtube, toggle

I'm using a Youtube-TV JS plugin for a client site (https://github.com/Giorgio003/Youtube-TV ). The player loads with a playlist in an open state, and I need to have it load with the toggle closed, showing the array of playlists, can anyone help?
my codepen for the player is here
http://codepen.io/raldesign/pen/OVYXvK

```
    (function(win, doc) {
    'use strict';
    var apiKey = 'AIzaSyAFMzeux_Eu933wk5U8skMzUzA-urgVgsY';
    var YTV = YTV || function(id, opts){

        var noop = function(){},
            settings = {
                apiKey: apiKey,
                element: null,
                user: null,
                channelId: null,
                fullscreen: false,
                accent: '#fff',
                controls: true,
                annotations: false,
                autoplay: false,
                chainVideos: true,
                browsePlaylists: false,
                playerTheme: 'dark',
                listTheme: 'dark',
                responsive: false,
                playId:'',
                sortList: false,
                reverseList: false,
                shuffleList: false,
                wmode: 'opaque',
                events: {
                    videoReady: noop,
                    stateChange: noop
                }
            },

            cache = {
                data: {},
                remove: function (url) {
                    delete cache.data[url];
                },
                exist: function (url) {
                    return cache.data.hasOwnProperty(url) && cache.data[url] !== null;
                },
                get: function (url) {
                    return cache.data[url];
                },
                set: function (url, data) {
                    cache.remove(url);
                    cache.data[url] = data;
                }
            },
            utils = {
                events: {
                    addEvent: function addEvent(element, eventName, func) {
                        if (element.addEventListener) {
                            return element.addEventListener(eventName, func, false);
                        } else if (element.attachEvent) {
                            return element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, func);
                        }
                    },
                    removeEvent: function addEvent(element, eventName, func) {
                        if (element.addEventListener) {
                            return element.removeEventListener(eventName, func, false);
                        } else if (element.attachEvent) {
                            return element.detachEvent("on" + eventName, func);
                        }
                    },
                    prevent: function(e) {
                        if (e.preventDefault) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        } else {
                            e.returnValue = false;
                        }
                    }
                },
                addCSS: function(css){
                    var head = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                        style = doc.createElement('style');
                        style.type = 'text/css';
                    if (style.styleSheet){
                        style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
                    } else {
                        style.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(css));
                    }
                    head.appendChild(style);
                },
                addCommas: function(str){
                    var x = str.split('.'),
                        x1 = x[0],
                        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '',
                        rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
                    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
                    }
                    return x1 + x2;
                },
                parentUntil: function(el, attr) {
                    while (el.parentNode) {
                        if (el.getAttribute && el.getAttribute(attr)){
                            return el;
                        }
                        el = el.parentNode;
                    }
                    return null;
                },
                ajax: {
                    get: function(url, fn){
                        if (cache.exist(url)) {
                            fn.call(this, JSON.parse(cache.get(url)));
                        } else {
                            var handle;
                            if (win.XDomainRequest && !(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 8")==-1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 9")==-1)) { // CORS for IE8,9
                                handle = new XDomainRequest();
                                handle.onload = function(){
                                    cache.set(url, handle.responseText);
                                    fn.call(this, JSON.parse(handle.responseText));
                                    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(JSON.parse(handle.responseText), 'error')){
                                        cache.remove(url);
                                        var e = JSON.parse(handle.responseText);
                                        console.log('Youtube-TV Error: Youtube API Response: '+e.error.errors[0].reason+'\n'+ 'Details: '+e.error.errors[0].message);
                                    }
                                };
                            } else if (win.XMLHttpRequest){ // Modern Browsers
                                handle = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
                            }
                            handle.onreadystatechange = function(){
                                if (handle.readyState === 4 && handle.status === 200){
                                    cache.set(url, handle.responseText);
                                    fn.call(this, JSON.parse(handle.responseText));
                                } else if (handle.readyState === 4){
                                    var e = JSON.parse(handle.responseText);
                                    console.log('Youtube-TV Error: Youtube API Response: '+e.error.errors[0].reason+'\n'+ 'Details: '+e.error.errors[0].message);
                                }
                            };
                            handle.open("GET",url,true);
                            handle.send();
                        }
                    }
                },
                endpoints: {
                    base: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/',
                    userInfo: function(){
                        return utils.endpoints.base+'channels?'+settings.cid+'&key='+apiKey+'&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics';
                    },
                    playlistInfo: function(pid){
                        return utils.endpoints.base+'playlists?id='+pid+'&key='+apiKey+'&maxResults=50&part=snippet';
                    },
                    userPlaylists: function(){
                        return utils.endpoints.base+'playlists?channelId='+settings.channelId+'&key='+apiKey+'&maxResults=50&part=snippet';
                    },
                    playlistVids: function(){
                        return utils.endpoints.base+'playlistItems?playlistId='+settings.pid+'&key='+apiKey+'&maxResults=50&part=contentDetails';
                    },
                    videoInfo: function(){
                        return utils.endpoints.base+'videos?id='+settings.videoString+'&key='+apiKey+'&maxResults=50&part=snippet,contentDetails,status,statistics';
                    }
                },
                deepExtend: function(destination, source) {
                    var property;
                    for (property in source) {
                        if (source[property] && source[property].constructor && source[property].constructor === Object) {
                            destination[property] = destination[property] || {};
                            utils.deepExtend(destination[property], source[property]);
                        } else {
                            destination[property] = source[property];
                        }
                    }
                    return destination;
                }
            },
            prepare = {
                youtube: function(){
                    if(typeof YT=='undefined'){
                        var tag = doc.createElement('script');
                        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                        var firstScriptTag = doc.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
                    }
                },
                build: function(){
                    if (settings.channelId){
                        settings.cid = 'id='+settings.channelId;
                    } else if(settings.user){
                        settings.cid = 'forUsername='+settings.user;
                    }
                    settings.element.className = "ytv-canvas";
                    if(settings.fullscreen){
                        settings.element.className += " ytv-full";
                    }
                    utils.addCSS( '#'+id+' .ytv-list .ytv-active a{border-left-color: '+(settings.accent)+';}' );
                    // Responsive CSS
                    if(settings.responsive){
                        utils.addCSS('#'+id+' .ytv-video{'
                            +'position: relative; padding-bottom: 39.4%; /* 16:9 of 70%*/'
                            +'height: 0; width: 70%;'
                            +'} #'+id+' .ytv-video iframe{'
                            +'position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;'
                            +'} #'+id+' .ytv-list{'
                            +'width: 30%;'
                            +'} #'+id+' .ytv-playlist-open .ytv-arrow{'
                            +'top: 0px;}'
                            +'@media only screen and (max-width:992px) {'
                            +'#'+id+' .ytv-list{'
                            +'position: relative; display: block;'
                            +'width: 0; padding-bottom: 40%;'
                            +'left: auto; right: auto;'
                            +'top: auto; width: 100%;'
                            +'} #'+id+' .ytv-video{'
                            +'position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */'
                            +'height: 0; position: relative;'
                            +'display: block; left: auto;'
                            +'right: auto; top: auto; width: 100%;'
                            +'}}'
                            );
                    }
                    // Temp Scroll Bar fix
                    if (settings.listTheme == 'dark'){
                        utils.addCSS( ' #'+id+'.ytv-canvas ::-webkit-scrollbar{border-left: 1px solid #000;}'
                            + ' #'+id+'.ytv-canvas ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);}');
                    }
                    // Optional Light List Theme
                    if(settings.listTheme == 'light'){
                        utils.addCSS( ' #'+id+'.ytv-canvas{background: #ccc;}'
                            + ' #'+id+'.ytv-canvas ::-webkit-scrollbar{border-left: 1px solid rgba(28,28,28,0.1);}'
                            + ' #'+id+'.ytv-canvas ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background: rgba(28,28,28,0.3);}'
                            + ' #'+id+' .ytv-list .ytv-active a{background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}'
                            + ' #'+id+' .ytv-list a{color: #282828; border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204,204,204,0.5);}'
                            + ' #'+id+' .ytv-list a:hover, #'+id+' .ytv-list-header .ytv-playlists a:hover{ background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}'
                            + ' #'+id+' .ytv-list a:active, #'+id+' .ytv-list-header .ytv-playlists a:active{ background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}'
                            + ' #'+id+' .ytv-list .ytv-thumb-stroke{outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}'
                            + ' #'+id+' .ytv-list .ytv-thumb{outline: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);}'
                            + ' #'+id+' .ytv-list-header{-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);}'
                            + ' #'+id+' .ytv-list-header a{background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}'
                            + ' #'+id+' .ytv-playlists{background: #ccc;}'
                            );
                    }
                },
                userUploads: function(userInfo){
                    if (userInfo && userInfo.items.length > 0){
                        settings.pid = userInfo.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
                        utils.ajax.get( utils.endpoints.playlistVids(), prepare.compileVideos );
                    } else console.log ('Youtube-TV Error: API returned no matches for: '+(settings.channelId ? settings.channelId : settings.user)+'\nPlease ensure it was entered correctly and in the appropriate field shown below. \nuser: \'username\' or channelId: \'UCxxxx...\'');
                },
                selectedPlaylist: function(playlistInfo){
                    if (playlistInfo && playlistInfo.items.length > 0) {
                        if (!settings.channelId && !settings.user){
                            settings.cid = ('id='+(settings.channelId = playlistInfo.items[0].snippet.channelId));
                        }
                        settings.currentPlaylist = playlistInfo.items[0].snippet.title;
                        settings.pid = playlistInfo.items[0].id;
                        utils.ajax.get( utils.endpoints.playlistVids(), prepare.compileVideos );
                    } else console.log ('Youtube-TV Error: API returned no matches for playlist(s): '+settings.playlist);
                },
                compileVideos: function(res){
                    if (res && res.items.length > 0){
                        var playlists = res.items,
                        i;
                        settings.videoString = '';
                        for(i=0; i<playlists.length; i++){
                            settings.videoString += playlists[i].contentDetails.videoId;
                            if (i<playlists.length-1){ settings.videoString += ',';}
                        }
                        utils.ajax.get( utils.endpoints.videoInfo(), prepare.compileList );
                    } else console.log ('Youtube-TV Error: Empty playlist');
                },
                playlists: function(res){
                    if(res && res.items.length > 0){
                        var list = '<div class="ytv-playlists"><ul>',
                            playlists = res.items,
                            i;
                        for(i=0; i<playlists.length; i++){
                            var data = {
                                title: playlists[i].snippet.title,
                                plid: playlists[i].id,
                                thumb: playlists[i].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url
                            };
                            list += '<a href="#" data-ytv-playlist="'+(data.plid)+'">';
                                list += '<div class="ytv-thumb"><div class="ytv-thumb-stroke"></div><img src="'+(data.thumb)+'"></div>';
                                list += '<span>'+(data.title)+'</span>';
                            list += '</a>';
                        }
                        list += '</ul></div>';

                        var lh = settings.element.getElementsByClassName('ytv-list-header')[0],
                            headerLink = lh.children[0];
                        headerLink.href="#";
                        headerLink.target="";
                        headerLink.setAttribute('data-ytv-playlist-toggle', 'true');
                        settings.element.getElementsByClassName('ytv-list-header')[0].innerHTML += list;
                        lh.className += ' ytv-has-playlists';
                    } else console.log ('Youtube-TV Error: Returned no playlists');
                },
                compileList: function(data){
                    if(data && data.items.length > 0){
                        utils.ajax.get( utils.endpoints.userInfo(), function(userInfo){
                            var list = '',
                                user = {
                                    title: userInfo.items[0].snippet.title,
                                    url: '//youtube.com/channel/'+userInfo.items[0].id,
                                    thumb: userInfo.items[0].snippet.thumbnails['default'].url,
                                    summary: userInfo.items[0].snippet.description,
                                    subscribers: userInfo.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount,
                                    views: userInfo.items[0].statistics.viewCount
                                },
                                videos = data.items,
                                first = true,
                                i;
                            settings.channelId = userInfo.items[0].id; 
                            if(settings.currentPlaylist) user.title += ' &middot; '+(settings.currentPlaylist);
                            if (settings.sortList) videos.sort(function(a,b){if(a.snippet.publishedAt > b.snippet.publishedAt) return -1;if(a.snippet.publishedAt < b.snippet.publishedAt) return 1;return 0;});
                            if (settings.reverseList) videos.reverse();
                            if (settings.shuffleList) {
                                videos = function (){for(var j, x, i = videos.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = videos[--i], videos[i] = videos[j], videos[j] = x);return videos;}();
                            }

                            list += '<div class="ytv-list-header">';
                                list += '<a href="'+(user.url)+'" target="_blank">';
                                    list += '<img src="'+(user.thumb)+'">';
                                    list += '<span><i class="ytv-arrow down"></i>'+(user.title)+'</span>';
                                list += '</a>';
                            list += '</div>';

                            list += '<div class="ytv-list-inner"><ul>';
                            for(i=0; i<videos.length; i++){
                                if(videos[i].status.embeddable){
                                    var video = {
                                        title: videos[i].snippet.title,
                                        slug: videos[i].id,
                                        link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+videos[i].id,
                                        published: videos[i].snippet.publishedAt,
                                        stats: videos[i].statistics,
                                        duration: (videos[i].contentDetails.duration),
                                        thumb: videos[i].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url
                                    };

                                    var durationString = video.duration.match(/[0-9]+[HMS]/g);
                                    var h = 0, m = 0, s = 0, time = '';
                                    durationString.forEach(function (duration) {
                                        var unit = duration.charAt(duration.length-1);
                                        var amount = parseInt(duration.slice(0,-1));
                                        switch (unit) {
                                            case 'H': h = (amount > 9 ? '' + amount : '0' + amount); break;
                                            case 'M': m = (amount > 9 ? '' + amount : '0' + amount); break;
                                            case 'S': s = (amount > 9 ? '' + amount : '0' + amount); break;
                                        }
                                    });
                                    if (h){ time += h+':';}
                                    if (m){ time += m+':';} else { time += '00:';}
                                    if (s){ time += s;} else { time += '00';}

                                    var isFirst = '';
                                    if(settings.playId==video.slug){
                                        isFirst = ' class="ytv-active"';
                                        first = video.slug;
                                    } else if(first===true){
                                        first = video.slug;
                                    }

                                    list += '<li'+isFirst+'><a href="#" data-ytv="'+(video.slug)+'" class="ytv-clear">';
                                    list += '<div class="ytv-thumb"><div class="ytv-thumb-stroke"></div><span>'+(time)+'</span><img src="'+(video.thumb)+'"></div>';
                                    list += '<div class="ytv-content"><b>'+(video.title)+'</b>';
                                    if (video.stats)
                                    {
                                        list+='</b><span class="ytv-views">'+utils.addCommas(video.stats.viewCount)+' Views</span>';
                                    }
                                    list += '</div></a></li>';
                                }
                            }
                            list += '</ul></div>';
                            settings.element.innerHTML = '<div class="ytv-relative"><div class="ytv-video"><div id="ytv-video-player"></div></div><div class="ytv-list">'+list+'</div></div>';
                            if(settings.element.getElementsByClassName('ytv-active').length===0){
                                settings.element.getElementsByTagName('li')[0].className = "ytv-active";
                            }
                            var active = settings.element.getElementsByClassName('ytv-active')[0];
                            active.parentNode.parentNode.scrollTop = active.offsetTop;
                            action.logic.loadVideo(first, settings.autoplay);

                            if (settings.playlist){
                                utils.ajax.get( utils.endpoints.playlistInfo(settings.playlist), prepare.playlists );
                            } else if(settings.browsePlaylists){
                                utils.ajax.get( utils.endpoints.userPlaylists(), prepare.playlists );
                            }

                        });
                    } else console.log ('Youtube-TV Error: Empty video list');
                }
            },
            action = {

                logic: {

                    playerStateChange: function(d){
                        console.log(d);
                    },

                    loadVideo: function(slug, autoplay){
                        var house = settings.element.getElementsByClassName('ytv-video')[0];
                        var counter = settings.element.getElementsByClassName('ytv-video-playerContainer').length;
                        house.innerHTML = '<div id="ytv-video-player'+id+counter+'" class="ytv-video-playerContainer"></div>';

                        cache.player = new YT.Player('ytv-video-player'+id+counter, {
                            videoId: slug,
                            events: {
                                onReady: settings.events.videoReady,
                                onStateChange: function(e){
                                    if( (e.target.getPlayerState()===0) && settings.chainVideos ){
                                        var ns = settings.element.getElementsByClassName('ytv-active')[0].nextSibling,
                                            link = ns.children[0];
                                        link.click();
                                    }
                                    settings.events.stateChange.call(this, e);
                                }
                            },
                            playerVars: {
                                enablejsapi: 1,
                                origin: doc.domain,
                                controls: settings.controls ? 1 : 0,
                                rel: 0,
                                showinfo: 0,
                                iv_load_policy: settings.annotations ? '' : 3, 
                                autoplay: autoplay ? 1 : 0,
                                theme: settings.playerTheme,
                                wmode: settings.wmode
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },

                endpoints: {
                    videoClick: function(e){
                        var target = utils.parentUntil(e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement, 'data-ytv');
                        if(target){
                            if(target.getAttribute('data-ytv')){
                                // Load Video
                                utils.events.prevent(e);
                                var activeEls = settings.element.getElementsByClassName('ytv-active'),
                                    i;
                                for(i=0; i<activeEls.length; i++){
                                    activeEls[i].className="";
                                }
                                target.parentNode.className="ytv-active";
                                action.logic.loadVideo(target.getAttribute('data-ytv'), true);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    playlistToggle: function(e){
                        var target = utils.parentUntil(e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement, 'data-ytv-playlist-toggle');
                        if(target && target.getAttribute('data-ytv-playlist-toggle')){
                            // Toggle Playlist
                            utils.events.prevent(e);
                            var lh = settings.element.getElementsByClassName('ytv-list-header')[0];
                            if(lh.className.indexOf('ytv-playlist-open')===-1){
                                lh.className += ' ytv-playlist-open';
                            } else {
                                lh.className = lh.className.replace(' ytv-playlist-open', '');
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    playlistClick: function(e){
                        var target = utils.parentUntil(e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement, 'data-ytv-playlist');

                        if(target && target.getAttribute('data-ytv-playlist')){

                            // Load Playlist
                            utils.events.prevent(e);

                            settings.pid = target.getAttribute('data-ytv-playlist');
                            target.children[1].innerHTML = 'Loading...';

                            utils.ajax.get( utils.endpoints.playlistInfo(settings.pid), function(res){
                                var lh = settings.element.getElementsByClassName('ytv-list-header')[0];
                                lh.className = lh.className.replace(' ytv-playlist-open', '');
                                prepare.selectedPlaylist(res);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                bindEvents: function(){
                    utils.events.addEvent( settings.element, 'click', action.endpoints.videoClick );
                    utils.events.addEvent( settings.element, 'click', action.endpoints.playlistToggle );
                    utils.events.addEvent( settings.element, 'click', action.endpoints.playlistClick );
                }
            },

            initialize = function(id, opts){
                utils.deepExtend(settings, opts);
                if(settings.apiKey.length===0){
                    alert("Missing APIkey in settings or as global vaiable.");
                }
                apiKey = settings.apiKey;
                settings.element = (typeof id==='string') ? doc.getElementById(id) : id;
                if(settings.element && (settings.user || settings.channelId || settings.playlist)){
                    prepare.youtube();
                    prepare.build();
                    action.bindEvents();
                    if (settings.playlist) {
                        utils.ajax.get( utils.endpoints.playlistInfo(settings.playlist), prepare.selectedPlaylist );
                    } else {
                        utils.ajax.get( utils.endpoints.userInfo(), prepare.userUploads );
                    }
                } else console.log ('Youtube-TV Error: Missing either user, channelId, or playlist');
            };

            /* Public */

            this.destroy = function(){
                utils.events.removeEvent( settings.element, 'click', action.endpoints.videoClick );
                utils.events.removeEvent( settings.element, 'click', action.endpoints.playlistToggle );
                utils.events.removeEvent( settings.element, 'click', action.endpoints.playlistClick );
                settings.element.className = '';
                settings.element.innerHTML = '';
            };
            this.fullscreen = {
                state: function(){
                    return (settings.element.className).indexOf('ytv-full') !== -1;
                },
                enter: function(){
                    if( (settings.element.className).indexOf('ytv-full') === -1 ){
                        settings.element.className += 'ytv-full';
                    }
                },
                exit: function(){
                    if( (settings.element.className).indexOf('ytv-full') !== -1 ){
                        settings.element.className = (settings.element.className).replace('ytv-full', '');
                    }
                }
            };

        initialize(id, opts);
    };

    if ((typeof module !== 'undefined') && module.exports) {
        module.exports = YTV;
    }
    if (typeof ender === 'undefined') {
        this.YTV = YTV;
    }
    if ((typeof define === "function") && define.amd) {
        define("YTV", [], function() {
            return YTV;
        });
    }
    if ((typeof jQuery !== 'undefined')) {
        jQuery.fn.extend({
            ytv: function(options) {
                return this.each(function() {
                    new YTV(this.id, options);
                });
            }
        });
    }
}).call(this, window, document);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
list += '<div class="ytv-list-header">';
```

with

```
list += '<div class="ytv-list-header ytv-playlist-open">';
```

There is two playlist one is "list of all playlists". And other is "list of videos in a playlist". 
"ytv-playlist-open" indicate the open status for "list of all playlist". So when it is added it will close "videos in a playlist" and show "list of all playlist" which you want to show there.